# Getting Image from Facebook and display on Iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

My app needs to get profile pic from Facebook (which I have already done). But I am stuck at how to use it. The picture I get is in .jpg format. I want to assign it to an UIImage object and display it dynamically.

HOw should I do it? Any easy way? 
Thanks

Comment: You say you have already retrieved the image. How have you retrieved it and how are you storing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://facebook.jpg"]; // facebook.jpg is the url of profile pic
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];
[self.view addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]]; //  or something similar
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you have the data contained in an NSData object I will call `pictureData`.

```
UIImage* profilePicture = [UIImage imageWithData:pictureData];
profilePictureView.image = profilePicture;
```

I prefer more deterministic memory allocation, however:

```
UIImage* profilePicture = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:pictureData];
profilePictureView.image = profilePicture;
[profilePicture release];
```

If you have the picture on disk, one cool trick is to memory-map it to avoid memory allocation:

```
NSData* picData = [NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfMappedFile:@"profile.jpg"];
UIImage* profilePic = [[UIImage alloc initWithData:picData];
[picData release];
profilePicView.image = profilePic;
[profilePic release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the UIImage class reference.
There is a class function + (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name

You can use UIImage *profilePicImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.jpg"];